error when trying to render a gym environment
I wrote and run this snippet of code some weeks ago, which it worked.
import gym
# Create predefined environment 
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1')

# Print environment in terminal
env.render() 

But now, after created a new conda environment, with the same version, it arises the next error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in                                                            NameError: name 'env' is not defined


env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1')                                                             >>> env
<TimeLimit<OrderEnforcing<PassiveEnvChecker<FrozenLakeEnv>>>>                    >>> env.render()
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 329, in render
return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)                                                       File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/order_enforcing.py", line 47, in render
raise ResetNeeded(
gym.error.ResetNeeded: Cannot call env.render() before calling env.reset(), if this is a intended action, set disable_render_order_enforcing=True on the OrderEnforcer wrapper.



If I write "env.reset()" as it says, it outputs "(0, {'prob': 1})", and then with "env.render()" it arises a new error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/core.py", line 329, in render
return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/order_enforcing.py", line 51, in render
return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/wrappers/env_checker.py", line 53, in render
return env_render_passive_checker(self.env, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py", line 316, in env_render_passive_checker
result = env.render(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py", line 273, in render
return self._render_gui(self.render_mode)
File "/home/javierac/anaconda3/envs/gym/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py", line 294, in _render_gui
self.window_surface is not None
AssertionError: Something went wrong with pygame. This should never happen.

I'm using Python 3.10.13 and I don't know why it doesn't work. Gym is installes as follows: conda install conda-forge::gym-all
Perphaps did I use another python version previously?
